# Could I get 'creationTime' when I create a new document in Firestore (instead of using 'documentRef.get()' after creation and thus avoid that reading?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

**Goal: get the creation time of a new Firestore document in the document creation process**

First I create a new document with the corresponding data `newDocumentData` and a field `creationTime` with the creation time, as shown below:

```js
const newDocumentRef = await collectionRef.add({
  ...newDocumentData,
  creationTime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})
```

Then, I need the `creationTime`, and I follow like this...

```js
const document = await newDocumentRef.get()
if (document.exists) {
  const documentData = document.data()
}
```

...to finally get my `documentData.creationTime`.

My question is: Is there any way to get `creationTime` with `newDocumentRef` in the first step and, therefore, avoiding the rest of the process?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible with the Client SDKs, "to get the value of `creationTime` **in the first step**". [`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-servertimestamp)  returns a sentinel value that tells **the server** to assign a server-generated timestamp in the written data.

In other words the exact value for `creationTime` will be **calculated by the server**, and if you want to get this value, **you need to query the database for it**.

---

Note that, on the other hand, with the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest), when you [create a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1.projects.databases.documents), you get back (i.e. through the API endpoint response) a [`Document`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents#Document) object that contains, among others, a `createTime` field.

Comment: Ok. I think it is not my case, I am not using the Firestore REST API... As the server returns a reference (newDocumentRef in the above code sample) in the first step, with the 'id' and other data (a firestore field, parent, etc), I was thinking about to have the creationTime among those data... and not to do the ref.get() because in some cases I only need the creation time. But no problem, I will do as before. Thanks!

Comment: I understand, it is not very easy to mix the use of the JS SDK with calls to the REST API, in particular if you have security rules in the DB... I was just mentioning the fact that with the REST API we get back the document (with some extra 'technical' fields) because it is interesting to note it, IMO.